# How make_int2 is working?

Tags: cuda, gpu

in the CUDA C Programming Guide Version there is a small paragraph about Built-in Vector Types. It says that this structure has 4 components and they accessible with a specific way, e.i `.x .y .z .w`. What are the 4 components? Can someone give an example?

Moreover it says that with this line `int2 make_int2(int x, int y);` it constructs a vector with value **x**, **y**. Each of these variables has 4 components?

The reason I am trying to understand these things is because I am studying the following code:

```
  /*1*/ int  ny             = num_ofElements_y_ofmyMatrix;
  /*2*/ int  nx             = num_ofElements_x_ofmyMatrix;
  /*3*/ int2 matrix_index_2d = make_int2( ( blockIdx.x * blockDim.x ) + threadIdx.x, ( blockIdx.y * blockDim.y ) + threadIdx.y );

  /*4*/ int  matrix_index_1d = ( nx * matrix_index_2d.y ) + matrix_index_2d.x;

  /*5*/ if ( matrix_index_2d.x < nx && matrix_index_2d.y < ny )
  /*6*/ {
  /*7*/   float r = myMatrix[ matrix_index_1d ];
  /*8*/ }
```

How the indexing in lines **3** and **4** is working? Subsequently, who does the access of the matrix **myMatrix** is working?

**UPDATE:**

As far as the code snippet is concerned usually when I am accessing an array I am using the following:

```
col = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threahIdx.x;
row = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threahIdx.x;
if (col < NUMCOLS && row < NUMROWS){...}
```

in order to have a row-major access of an array in c++, e.g `myMatrix[row*NUMCOLS + col]`.

What is the connection with the type of indexing used in line **3** and **4**?

Comment: Concerning your update, coalesced global memory access is obtained with `int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;`, `int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;` and `gmem[y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x + x]`. This seems to be consistent with lines `3` and `4`, provided that the kernel is launched with `nx = blockDim.x * gridDim.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the CUDA built-in vector types have `4` components. For example, `double2` has `2` `double` components. `double2` is indeed defined as

```
struct __device_builtin__ __builtin_align__(16) double2
{
    double x, y;
};
```

and can be used to deal with complex, double precision numbers. According to the definition above, you can use a declaration like

```
double2 foo;
```

and then initialize the two int2 make_int2(int x, int y); and `y` components as

```
foo.x = 1.;
foo.y = 3.4;
```

As another example, `float4` has `4` `float` components and can be used to deal with four-vector in a Minkowski space.

In your example, `int2` has `2` integer components and the instruction

```
int2 foo_int = make_int2(3,1);
```

constructs a `foo_int` struct of type `int2` and initializes the `x` and `y` components to `3` and `1` respectively.

Comment: In addition, refer to the header files `/usr/local/cuda/include/vector_types.h` for an understanding of the various different vector types that are defined there as well as `/usr/local/cuda/include/vector_functions.h` for the various "constructors".

Comment: @RobertCrovella I had in mind to add that information, but you are always too fast :-) Anyway, let me mention that, under Windows, those files are located at `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include`.